# py.test reporting IndexError/KeyError as a Failure instead of Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

```
 import unittest
 import logging

 FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
 logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)


 log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 log.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

 class FixturesTest(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUp(self):
         log.info('starting setup')
         self.fixture = range(1, 10)
         log.warn('Hello world')

     def tearDown(self):
         log.info('starting teardown')
         del self.fixture
         log.info('Goodbye world')

     def test_pass(self):
         log.info('in test pass')
         self.assertEqual(self.fixture, range(1, 10))
         log.error('Test world')

     def test_fail(self):
         log.info('in test fail')
         log.error("let's fail a test")
         assert(1==0)

     def test_error(self):
         log.info('in test error')
         log.info("let's error a test")
         d = []
         d[1]

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         unittest.main()
```

running the above code using py.test, it reports the test_error test method as a test failure instead of test error. whereas running it using unittest shows the test_error as an error instead of failure, could you share any thoughts on this?

Update : Same code, nose also consider it as an error instead of failure for the test_error, is this an issue in py.test ??

Update : If you are not sure what I refer by this, if you run py.test test_filename.py, you get 1 pass, 2 failures, if you run python -m unittest test_filename.py or nosetest test_filename.py, it's 1 pass, 1 failure, 1 error.

Comment: printing the code with the code lines isn't very convenient...

Comment: can you clarify your question

Comment: `py.test` treats any exception raised from test method as a failure. Errors, on the other hand, are for cases when fixture setup/teardown does not end well.

Answer (score 2):

pytest doesn't differentiate from test *failures* (due to an `AssertionError`) and test *errors* (any other exception) like `unittest` does. This is not a bug, but by design.

There's been some discussion in [this thread](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1555) to add support for this type of separation and it resulted in the [pytest-finer-verdicts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-finer-verdicts) plugin.